# My blog is not showing correctly through IE? In Chrome it works fine though.

Tags: blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

I installed customized template for my blog through Blogger. The blog was showing okay in Google Chrome. However, when I looked up the blog in IE, the columns on the top menu bar become vertical layout other than horizontal layout. Also the social sharing icons under each post become white boxes and people can't tell what they are really. Can you please help and let me know what could go wrong? Thanks a lot.

My blog address is http://www.homediyinspirations.com

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the following tag is present in your template HTML (Accessible via Template > Edit HTML) -

```
<meta content='IE=EmulateIE7' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
```

Replace it with -

```
<meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
```

The `IE=EmulateIE7` tag causes the blog to be rendered as if it is being opened in Internet Explorer 7 browser (Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6771584/933980) for more information)

Comment: Yes, it works!! The problem has gone. Thank you so much! This is a really good forum that has all experts in it.